# php variable scope trouble

Tags: php, html

How I can get access to variable scope in different php file? For example:

one.php:

```
<?php $var1 = true; ?>
```

two.php:

```
<?php if( $var1 == true ) ?>
```

Comment: If it's a variable that you use regularly it may be worth setting up a config file which you would then include in all your PHP files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
include("one.php");
```

Done.
(see what I did there? ;))